# Hibernate: "Could not synchronize database state with session" on flush

Tags: hibernate, exception

I am receiving the "Could not synchronize database state with session" when I attempt a flush in my unit test below.

Can anyone advise what the problem is as I am completely lost? I have tried just creating a RuleDefinition without any of its attributes set and that doesn't work either.

Thanks

This is a snippet of my unit test which extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests

```
@Test
public void testCreateRule() {
    RuleDefinition ruleReturned = (RuleDefinition) hibernateRuleDefinitionDao.findRule(1);
    RuleDefinition newRule = new RuleDefinition();
    newRule.setCurrentState("ACTIVE");
    newRule.setAttribute(ruleReturned.getSecondaryAttribute());
    newRule.setSecondaryAttribute(ruleReturned.getAttribute());
    newRule.setOperator(ruleReturned.getOperator());
    newRule.setPrecedence(4);
    hibernateRuleDefinitionDao.createRule(newRule);
    // Exception is thrown after the flush
    hibernateTemplate.flush();   
}
```

The DAO method simply calls a save operation. This is my mapping file

```
<class name="abc.def.rules.RuleDefinition" table="REFDATA.CONFIG_RULE_DEFINITION">
    <id name="ruleId" column="RULE_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="attribute" cascade="none" class="abc.def.rules.ConfigAttribute" lazy="false" column="CONFIG_ATTR_ID"/>
    <many-to-one name="operator" cascade="none" class="abc.def.rules.Operator" lazy="false">
        <column name="OPRTR_VAL"/>
        <column name="OPRTR_VAL_DATA_TYP"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="secondaryAttribute" cascade="none" class="abc.def.rules.ConfigAttribute" lazy="false" column="CONFIG_ATTR_ID_2" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="operand" column="OPRND_VAL" type="string"/>
    <property name="trueAction" column="TRUE_ACTN" type="string"/>
    <property name="falseAction" column="FALSE_ACTN" type="string"/>
    <property name="precedence" column="RULE_ORD_SEQ" type="int" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="currentState" column="RULE_STAT" type="string"/>
</class>
```

This is a snippet of my Spring configuration file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:abc\def\hibernate-reference.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
                false
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: do you have a inverse mapping to **RuleDefinition**  from **ConfigAttribute** or **Operator**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolved this myself. My CONFIG_RULE_DEFINITION had a constraint specifying that a Timestamp column should be not null and should default to SYSDATE. However, SYSDATE does not work in HSQLDB I presume. For some reason, no such error was propogating up to notify me of this. Once I removed this constraint all worked fine!